# Building Hibernate 3.2.0 on Linux OS 64 bit

Tags: linux, hibernate, centos

I need to build the jars for Hibernate 3.2.0 but I am having trouble finding directions. I am trying to follow along in the tutorial but it is wanting me to create classes and other files, is that really necessary just to compile the jars? I need to compile on a 64 bit Linux CentOS machine.

Also the directions in the tutorial are for 3.5 or 3.6 and they say to use maven but when I downloaded the source it came with a build.xml file, so am I supposed to use ant? and when I try ant it tells me I am missing antl/tools.

I am a brand new intern and I am just trying to figure this out so I can do what is asked of me. Any help would be greatly apprecited.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: It seems you're asking about how to build hibernate itself - if you only want to use hibernate, you don't need to build it. You can download the precompiled jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For branch 3.2, you'll just need to run the `run.sh` (Linux) or `run.bat` (Windows). It should be enough. But keep in mind that 3.2 is an old branch. If you are developing a new application, consider using a newer version (3.6, for instance).

Comment: [root@localhost hibernate-3.2]# sh build.sh
Buildfile: build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource clovertasks. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
' does not exist in this project. 

Total time: 0 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Binaries for Hibernate 3.2 can be downloaded from their [SourceForge project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/). Hibernate distributions typically contain `hibernate3.jar`, dependent jars, reference manuals and source files. The jars can be used on any JVM with version higher than 1.5 (or 1.4, I don't remember precisely) available on 64-bit CentOS.

Comment: right, so I downloaded that already and there is a build.xml file and when I run ant it always fails, there is no documentation